# Automatic timestamp in ArcGIS Collector

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-collector

I've been using ArcGIS collector for field surveys and measurements. I would like the app to automatically populate a field with latest update time when I enter values in the fields I'm interested in.

Is that possible? I'd like to avoid using tracking, which seem to be a possible workaround when googling.

Comment: I think Editor Tracking is going to be your best bet.  Is there any particular reason you want to avoid doing this?

Comment: Maybe I misinterpreted the tracking part, I thought it was connected to tracking where I'd been. I'd prefer avoiding using credits, if possible, that was the reason not to use tracking.

Comment: Ahh, yes this is just editor tracking for your attribute table.  It will add times tamps any time attributes have been modified and will tell who the last editor was.  Using Editor Tracking will not consume any credits, it just adds a few extra fields to your data.

Comment: I see, clearly a misunderstandning on my part. I'll check it out, but it sounds promising! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup enable editor tracking on the service and that will collect the creator of the feature and the creation date along with the editor and the edit date. When a feature is updated multiple times the editor and the edit date fields will be updated to correspond with the most recent changes.

Comment: I have now tested this and it doesn't seem to work as I expected it to. If I update attributes (or even geometry) in Collector (offline mode) the EditDate field doesn't change on syncronization. It's only updating if I edit in AOL, which obviously isn't very useful for tracking field data collection... Am I still doing something terribly wrong, or is this someting you have experienced as well?

Comment: It should update when sync'ed. Are you using a hosted feature service or an ArcGIS Server service.

Comment: Yeah, well, that's what I thought. I have a feature layer that I upload from Arcmap (so hosted service), which I take offline on my phone and edit when out. But when syncing it doesn't update the EditDate value, it is still the creation date. If you haven't heard of this before I guess I should contact ESRI and see what they have to say about it :)

Comment: Are you checking the editor tracking in the popup of the app? I did a quick test on iOS and it will show the old value b/c the popup is not reloaded. If you close the popup and re-open the feature you will see the editor tracking updated to "edited seconds ago" instead of the old edit date.

Comment: Nah, after I sync I open the map in ArcGIS desktop and look at the attribute table of the layer I have edited. Btw, I use Android on my device, if that makes any difference.

Comment: That could be the difference. I will charge up my Android device and check it out. One thing to note - do you see the correct editor tracking in AGOL after you sync, and in ArcMap are you using the hosted service or a local copy, you might need to create a new local copy to grab the changes.

Comment: It wont update the EditDate at all, not even in AGOL. Still just showing the create date even though the new values are all there. I will send something to ESRI as well, and see what they have to say.

Comment: I tried this earlier this morning with the latest release of Collector on Android and I could not repro the issue you are seeing but I do work at Esri  (not directly on Collector) but I have passed this along to a member of the team to look into it and see if there is an open issue.

Comment: I was in contact with ESRI support here in Sweden and we got it working if I instead of a shapefile used a gdb feature with edit tracking already enabled when published to AGOL. However, the problem with shapefiles seem to persist, but at least I can use the function now. She also told me that they would investigate further what could be the cause, so hopefully it'll get to the right people from more than one direction now! Thanks for all your help with this, really appreciate it!

Comment: (And of course, it is entirely possible that I actually was doing something wrong, but if so none of us have been able to find out what yet.)